# Add a new custom api method definition to Jest namespace

Tags: javascript, angular, jestjs, angular10

I was using Jasmine earlier as a testing platform for my angular and I recently moved to jest framework as it provides more benefits as a testing platform.

while I was migrating all my existing UT's to Jest, I found that some of the API's are not readily supported by Jest,
eg: `createSpyObj(...)`

and for this I had to create a helper method using `jest.fn()` as below

```
const createSpyObj = (object: string, methods?: string[], properties?: any) => {
   const obj: any = {};

   for (const method of methods) {
     obj[method] = jest.fn();
   }

   for (const key of Object.keys(properties)) {
     obj[key] = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(properties[key]);
   }

   return obj;
 };
```

this works fine however, I wanted to add this to the Jest namespace so that I don't have to define it in every single test file.

**This is what I did so far(followed this article, [add custom API to jest](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2020/01/30/jest-add-custom-functions/#comment-651784)):**

1. created a file `jest.d.ts` with the below code  and added this file path inside  `"include": [...,"./jest.d.ts"],` inside `tsconfig.json`

   ```
   declare namespace jest {
      function createSpyObj<T>(object: string, methods?: string[], properties?: any): T;
   }
   ```
2. created a file `jest.setup.ts` with below code & added it to `"setupFilesAfterEnv":["<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts",],` inside jest.config.json

   ```
    jest.createSpyObj = (object: string, methods?: string[], properties?: any) => {
      const obj: any = {};

      for (const method of methods) {
        obj[method] = jest.fn();
      } 

      for (const key of Object.keys(properties)) {
        obj[key] = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(properties[key]);
      }

      return obj;
    };
   ```

**What's the problem?**
Getting error in `jest.setup.ts` as *"Property 'createSpyObj' does not exist on type 'typeof jest'"*.

But when I use the new API `jest.createdSpyObj(...)` inside my tests, I don't get any compile-time errors, which means that the new method declaration is working fine, but fails at run-time.

**Any quick help would be really appreciated**

Comment: It's a bad practice to extend API that doesn't belong to you for your own needs. If you need to make createSpyObj available in tests, you could make it a global, so it would be `declare var createSpyObj`. Try `typeRoots` to specify custom typings, not `include`.

Comment: @EstusFlask, your right about that, but I am not altering the existing definition of the lib, just monkey patching it.  

so that I can use it as `jest.createSpyObj` which more or less looks the same as jasmine lib's syntax.

Comment: @EstusFlask btw, do you have any examples to try out using `typeRoots` ?